# Build failing for android with error "Execution failed for task ':react-native-fcm:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.", but working for iOS

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, react-native-fcm

I am facing this issue with android release suddenly. Till Friday everything was working fine, but build is getting failed today with error. i have attached the detailed error in screenshot
[image: That is the error i am facing now for android build. working fine for iOS]

Comment: What is your react-native version ?

Comment: "react-native": "0.56.0"

Comment: If you go through the documentation then you should integrate react-native-firebase instead of react-native-fcm

Comment: i agree, but till friday , everything was working smoothly. Suddenly this error. Documentation is also saying  "react-native-fcm will still take PRs and bug fixes, but possibly no new feature developement any more."

Comment: Did you change google play services version.?

Comment: no, I just made a slight change in my component.

Comment: What you can do is clear the cache of android studio and restart it. To invalidate cache and restart what you can do is click on file menu and you will find that option i.e invalidate caches/Restart.

Comment: Still same issue !! didn't work

Comment: are google services been used by any other library?

Comment: Start the app from the scratch. By restarting android studio and opening project by selecting build.gradle file.

Comment: nothing worked man :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced similar error today, it is due to deprecation of certain firebase classes used by react-native-fcm. You can either rewrite the functions or do the below.
Go to build.gradle for react-native-fcm and change it to look like the below code.

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar'
}
```

By default gradle was getting the latest firebase-core and firebase-messaging (specified by +) and this was causing the error. Make sure to clean the project and re-build it.

Comment: What is the version of React-native-fcm you are using ?